# How to correct: My mother tends to take too many things with us when go a travel

Tags: grammar

**Question**: My mother tends to take too many things with us when go a travel.

**Book Answer**: when go a travel --> when go on a travel

In my opinion, shouldn't it instead be "when going on a travel"? I'm not sure if the answer in the book is correct.

Comment: You might need to find a better book to learn English from.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Actually, neither of those are correct. "Travel" is not usually used as a noun, and when it is, it's not used to refer to a specific journey, but rather the act of traveling in general as in, "My job requires a lot of travel". Talking about "a travel" is not correct in any circumstance.

Correct ways to write this would be:

My mother tends to take too many things with us when traveling.

My mother tends to take too many things with us when going on a trip.